# Updating particle position

Tags: c++, vector, particles, particle-system

I'm just starting with C++, and I'm trying to practice it with a simple Particle system with SDL and GLM.

For now the particle emitter emits 1 particle (before the game loop). Then I call the update method for every particle in the vector (just 1). But for some reason my particle position itn't 'saved'? I feel really dumb, but I really can't figure this out.

main.cpp loop & emit invoke:

```
emitter.emit();
while (display.IsRunning()) {
    display.Clear();

    emitter.render();

    display.Update();
}
```

ParticleEmitter.cpp:

```
#include "ParticleEmitter.h"
#include "glm\glm.hpp"
#include "GL\glew.h"

using namespace glm;

ParticleEmitter::ParticleEmitter(vec2 position) : position(position)
{
}

void ParticleEmitter::emit() {
    Particle p(this);
    particles.push_back(p);
}

void ParticleEmitter::render() {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        for (Particle p : particles) {
            p.update();
            p.render();
        }
    glEnd();
}
```

Particle.cpp:

```
#include "Particle.h"
#include "glm\glm.hpp"
#include "GL\glew.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

Particle::Particle(ParticleEmitter *parentEmitter) : parentEmitter(parentEmitter)
{

}

void Particle::render() {
    glVertex2f(position.x, position.y);
}

void Particle::update() {
    float y = position.y;
    cout << "Y: " << y << endl;
    float tmp = y - 0.01;
    cout << "TMP: " << tmp << endl;
    position.y = tmp;
}
```

Note that particles in the emitter is a vector of Particles

The output is:

[image: Console output]

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 4):

Your range based for loop is taking the Particles by value, so their value is never saved. Try changing:

```
for (Particle p : particles)
```

to

```
for (Particle &p : particles)
```

Comment: Wow. Just. Awesome. Thanks alot. Feel so dumb now lol. Oh well, still learning! Thanks again. Will accept asap.

Comment: It's a really easy mistake to make. I only noticed it because I've done the same thing countless times. :)

Comment: Yeh, coming from Java this definitely is new!